# Why is there a KEY ERROR in one place but no KEY ERROR in another similar statement?

Tags: python, pandas, series, keyerror

I made a PANDAS Series in the first line of the code below. But I can't understand why
there is an error in the 3rd line but no error in the 2nd line. Please run the code in Jupyter in 3 separate blocks and help me if you understood the cause of error in 3rd line.

```
data = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 7, 8])
data['g']=5 # NO ERROR.
data[9] = 7 # WHY ERROR ??
```

Comment: Didn't you get the warning? ```FutureWarning: Treating integers as positional in Series.__setitem__ with a Float64Index is deprecated. In a future version, `series[an_int] = val` will insert a new key into the Series. Use `series.iloc[an_int] = val` to treat the key as positional.```. In the meantime you can use `data.loc[9] = 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pandas `loc()` function to avoid this error:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 7, 8])
data['g'] = 5
data.loc[9] = 7
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
7    4
8    5
g    5
9    7
dtype: int64
```